# impresion del lado del servidor

Tags: javascript, c#, impresión

Cual es la mejor forma de imprimir un HTML del lado del servidor?.
Estoy generando un HTML del lado del cliente (con javascript y css) para imprimirlo (usando window.print()). No quiero también tener que generarlo del lado del servidor la impresión. Quiero poder pasar al Servidor el HTML generado del lado del cliente para que éste lo imprima en alguna de sus impresoras. Es la mejor práctica?

Comment: Podrias explicar un poco mas pq queres imprimir algo del lado del servidor? pq la impresion requiere de alguien controlandola...

Comment: es una factura y quiero que se impriman todas en el servidor sin tener que tener la impresora en mi maquina local, tengo algún cliente que me ha solicitado esto. Mi maquina no tiene por que ver la impresora pero, el servidor si. Depende de la realidad del cliente, si la factura la imprimo en mi maquina local o en el servidor (una impresora vista desde el servidor). Si la imprimo de forma local, la impresion la hago con window.print() quiero saber como hacerla en el server, pasando el html armado para window.print() y no tener que armar tambien la impresion en el servidor con c#.

Comment: no deberias guardar eso en algun tipo de archivo? y que despues alguien haga las impresiones que quiera? digo, porque pienso que pasa si se traba la impresora? si se queda sin papel? tu sistema deja de funcionar porque el servidor no puede imprimir? Es una buena pregunta.. solo me genera esas dudas..

Comment: El sistema tiene posibilidad de reimprimir la factura, obviamente que esta queda grabada en tablas pero no queda grabada la impresión.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma bastante fácil de hacerlo es usando [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) que es un Qt WebKit rendering engine del lado del servidor

- Instalas wkhtmltopdf
- Ejecutas `wkhtmltopdf /ruta/a/tu/html/ejemplo.html ejemplo.pdf` en el servidor
- Con el pdf del lado del servidor, puedes guardarlo, mostrarlo etc.

Lo único que hay que tener en cuenta son las rutas, pero va a funcionar javascript, css, todo.

Como apunta @JackNavaRow, hay que darle permiso de ejecución, pero se supone que nuestro código y el wkhtmltopdf está fuera del document root. Otro tema a tener en cuenta es que hay que tener cuidado con el [Cross-site scripting](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) porque estamos ejecutando JavaScript del lado del servidor.

Comment: @JackNavaRow si, hay que tener cuidado de varias cosas, actualicé la respuesta, gracias por el aporte.